# CSS Selector problems

Tags: css, css-selectors

**I have a what i think is a selector problem, but not quite sure.**

In the image carousel i want the .nav labels to have an opacity of 0.5
when class of .slide is hovered. But Strangely this only works for the
last slide in the carousel, in the included codepen that would be slide 4.

First i thought that it was an layering issue, since the last slide comes
last in the DOM and that somehow affected it. So i tried to se if i could fix it with z-index but didn't work it out.

So i thought that it maybe is the input:checked selector that didn't set 
.nav labels to display block on the first slides but since they appear when
i hover straight over them they show and they point to the right slides so
that would mean that the right .nav labels are set to display block.

the only thing i can think of now that is wrong is the selector on row 64-65. but i am not sure, i think i have tried almost everything.

**Sass cutout:**

```
.slide
  display: block
  opacity: 0
  position: absolute
  top: 0
  width: 960px
  height: 420px
  transform: scale(1.8) rotate(12deg)
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out

  &:hover + .nav label
    opacity: 0.5

.nav label
  position: absolute
  top: 0
  display: none
  font-family: 'Varela Round'
  font-size: 250px
  line-height: 380px
  color: #ffffff
  width: 100px
  height: 100%
  text-align: center
  opacity: 0
  z-index: 9
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119)
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)

  &:hover
    opacity: 1
```

se the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNqEqM) for the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add z-index = 3 at here input:checked + .slide-container .slide should fix the problem.

The reason for that is because your other .slide have the same level with the current one, so when you hover the current slide, it hovers the last slide instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. that fixed my problem. i was trying to set z-index to it yesterday night but i probably had something else wrong at that time so i had taken that option of the table so i thank you so much for spotting that out for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried fooling around with your code in the codepen, and I got the results you wanted by fixing your CSS under the `.nav label` class.

Change `display: none` to `display: block`

Simple.

I can't say why this fixes it, or why your code wasn't working beforehand  though... it seems to have something to  do with the`input :checked` pseudo-class being applied to the fourth image in your `.nav label` class and ignoring the other  images.

Check out https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/ for more information on the behavior of `input:checked` and its usages with class  selectors, radio buttons, and checkbox inputs.

Comment: This actually doesn't fix the problem because now it is the slide4 nav that is showing all the time instead, even when you hover the nav label directly. somehow it overrides the other because it is later in the DOM? Or as if the &:hover .nav label always points to the last slides nav. tried to do it your way to. but thanks anyway.

Comment: Ah. You're right. Sorry for the premature response. Hope that it helped get you closer to isolating the problem though.